# How to perform a sum (addition) with values from a class?

Tags: python, class

I have code that I've been given:

```
import math

class shape(object):
    """Shape is an base class, which is largely intended to be abstract, that
    is only used as a parent class to other classes wich define specific shapes
    and inherit the shape class' fuctions getArea() and printArea().
    """

    def __init__(self):
        '''constructor function for the shape class
        '''
        self.area = None
        self.name = "shape"

    def getArea(self):
        '''returns the area of the shape, which is defined in the constructor
        '''
        return self.area

    def printArea(self):
        '''prints a statement identifying the shape by its name and giving the
        area of the shape. Returns None.
        '''
        print "The area of this " + self.name + " is: " + str(self.area)
        return None
```

I can't change any of the above. I was tasked with building on that class:

```
class rectangle(shape):
    """A new class 'rectangle' that will inherit functions from the class
    'shape'.
    """

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        """A constructor function for the class.
        """
        self.name = "rectangle"
        self.area = width * height

r = rectangle(2, 3)

r.printArea()


class triangle(shape):
    """A new class 'triangle' that will inherit functions from the class
    'shape'.
    """

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        """A constructor function for the class.
        """
        self.name = "triangle"
        self.area = (width * height) / 2.0

t = triangle(3, 4)

t.printArea()
```

Now I have to sum the areas of the rectangle and triangle together outside of the classes. How would I go about doing this? My attempt is drastically wrong and I don't really know what I'm doing with this:

```
def sumAreaOfShapes(shapeList):
    """The sum of all the areas of the shapes in the list.
    """
    addition = str(t.getArea()) + str(r.getArea())
    return addition

print sumAreaOfShapes([rectangle(1.5, 7), triangle(7, 12)])
```

All that does is literally stick one number on the end of another.

Edit: I've come slightly closer to what I'm looking for, but it's still no good.

```
def sumAreaOfShapes(shapeList):
"""The sum of all the areas of the shapes in the list.
"""
addition = (float(t.getArea()))+(float(c.getArea()))+(float(r.getArea()))
return addition

print sumAreaOfShapes([circle(100), rectangle(100, 100), triangle(100, 100)])
```

I get an answer now, but it's about 90.00, so it's actually summing the values from the class, and not from my print.

Comment: *"all that does is literally stick one number on the end of another"* - and what precisely did you expect from `str(t.getArea()) + str(r.getArea())`? Why convert them to strings if you want to treat them as numbers?

Comment: `sum` and don't cast the numbers to str, each rectangle has an `area` attribute so that is what you sum

Comment: Float wouldn't work for some reason. And triangle wouldn't be an integer if I changed the numbers, so I couldn't use that either.

Comment: `return sum(r.area() for r in shapeList)`

Comment: Your area formula is for a right triangle, you might want to be more specific in naming the class.

Comment: @tablue,  I think you need to read a tutorial or two http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/,  manually doing the addition makes zero sense,  the instances should be coming from `shapeList`

Comment: @fiarce: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it's strictly for a right-angled triangle.

Comment: @Padraic: Thanks, that link looks infinitely much more easier to read than all the advanced stuff out there. I'll check it out right away!

Comment: @tablue, yes, there are lots of easy to understand example for pretty much all the basics, if you understand the basics well it will make life much easier.

Comment: I recommend reading about Python's `@property`, idealy the area should be calculated based on the object's attributes instead of setting it in the constructor. The way it is currently implemented, if you'll change the width the area won't change - potential bug!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a bulit-in function `sum` with a generator expression:

```
def sumAreaOfShapes(shapeList):
     return sum(x.getArea() for x in shapeList)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So that's how you do it. I'll definitely learn from this.  I have a vague idea on why a list was made - to add the numbers up, but I can't really explain it since I started python a few days ago.

Comment: @Padric Cunningham Thanks for your advice

Comment: @tablue: If an answer is helpful, remember accept it.